# Detect the corner of the gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that can rotate an object by touch or mouse on it but I want to rotate the object when mouse goes over the corner of the object only. How can I do this?

The code I'm using is

```
private float baseAngle = 0.0f;

void OnMouseDown(){
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    baseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    baseAngle -= Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) *Mathf.Rad2Deg;
}

void OnMouseDrag(){
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    float ang = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) *Mathf.Rad2Deg - baseAngle;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang, Vector3.forward);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put invisible `GameObjects` or `RectTransforms` onto the corners of your object you want to rotate, and use them as the controls for the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

**One way of doing so would be to add colliders to the corners of your object.**

Using OnCollisionStay(), you could then trigger the appropriate functions when the mouse button is pressed. I've done similar myself, and this way does work.

**Another method to the madness:**

You could raycast where you are clicking, if your raycast is within an appropriate distance to the corners (which you could calculate based on its dimensions) then permit the rotation on click.